# TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, constructor, electron

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
```

With just these 2 lines of code, I am getting: `TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor`

Answer (score -1):

`require('electron')` returns an object with several members, among which appears `BrowserWindow`. In order to access it:

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron')
```

should be replaced by:

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow
```

or, making use of the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
```

Comment: The issue persists even after trying the suggestion.